# Commenting Cassandra's keyspace, table, column

Tags: cassandra, comments

In Oracle there is possibility to [add a comment](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4009.htm) about a table, view, materialized view, or column into the data dictionary, e.g.

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN employees.job_id 
   IS 'abbreviated job title';
```

I found this particularly usefull as a tester when trying to understand ideas behind the names which are not necessarily self-explanable and in large databases (over 200 tables).

Is there such feature in Cassandra?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use 'with comment' option

```
cqlsh:d2> 
cqlsh:d2> create table employee (id int primary key, name text) with comment = 'Employee id and name';
cqlsh:d2> desc table employee;

CREATE TABLE d2.employee (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = 'Employee id and name'
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

[Cassandra documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html#reference_ds_v3f_vfk_xj__setting-a-table-property)

Comment: Great. What about commenting each column separately? `with comment` doesn't seem to work on this level.

Comment: @dzieciou, commenting each column separately is not supported. One option that I can think of is, include comments about columns along with table comments.  Note that comments are stored as text in system.schema_columnfamilies table.

Comment: @ArunJoyThekkiniyath, thanks, but that doesn't scale for tables with >5 columns ;-)

Comment: @Arun - could you please take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077477/unable-to-create-a-table-with-comment